# How to open the application from my android application with no launcher

Tags: android, android-manifest, launcher

I have 3 android applications. One main application call other 2 applications (main application will be interface for other 2 applications). I would like to have only one icon of this main app.  I have 3 applications they can be downloaded separately. Now I need the other applications to check if the  main application is installed. If not, download and install main app. But how can I do that, if the secondary applications haven't got LAUNCHER ? Is there any way to do install main app from app without launcher  ?

Main app has android manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Secondary app has manifest (because do not want icon)

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Yes I know how to use code in app where is launcher to check app is installed, but dont want how to operate with, when the launcher is not.

```
        if (installed==false) { 
        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com......))
        .setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Or second question: is it possible to install app with launcher and then uninstall/hide icon of this app ? Let's say simple I will install all aplications with launcher and then after installation and settings hide icon of app, so that stay only icon of main application.

It looks strange for me, there is not any simple way to do that, simple set if icon will be visible or not. The same as you install software on Windows and you can set during installation if icon will be visible on desktop.

Comment: To me this sounds like a design-flaw. As a user, I would not expect an App to only work when another application is installed, too.

Comment: So there is no chance to do it ? Lets say simple I need to have 3 applications it can be download separately. One of them is interface. I need every application start after its installation to check if the other applications are present but create only one icon, it starts application interface.

Comment: One should be able to do that, by not registering the intent-filter for `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` and then using the complete package plus activity-class to start an activity. But as I said: as a user, I wouldn't expect this.